# local ring (exact one maximal ideal)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

Show that

> $R$ is local if and only if for every choice of finite elements $r_1, ..., r_m \in R$ this implication applies: $$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{m}r_i \in R^* \implies\exists i \in\{1,...,m\}\text{ with }r_i \in R^*.$$

Now I already got: "$\Rightarrow$" and for "$\Leftarrow$" the case if there can only be one maximal ideal (if we suppose that there is more than one maximal ideal). But I don't know how to show the existance of a maximal ideal. Please give me a hint.

Comment: The more common version of this question is: "R is local if the set of nonunits is closed under addition."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every (commutative, unital) ring has at least one maximal ideal. You can show any proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal using Zorn's lemma, and any non-unit of $R$ generates a proper ideal.

Comment: I thought that's only given if you talk of a noetherian ring

Comment: @milui If you don't like the axiom of choice, then you need the ring to be Noetherian (or something like it) for it to have a maximal ideal. If you like the axiom of choice, the existence of maximal ideals follow from Zorn's lemma, without any assumptions on $R$ other than it being, for instance, a commutative, unital ring.

Comment: ok thank you :)